# Test case to verify invocation even after one of the dependency call throws exception

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, tdd, testng

In my method, I invoke two dependencies depA.foo() & depB.bar(). If depA throws exception, then I don't want depB to be invoked. (NOT vice versa). So in the codebase, call to depA should be before call to B.

Is there a way to write test case to test invocation of depB() without explicity catching exception thrown by invocation A?

I could do this by putting verify() in finally block, but not sure if this is the correct way. Please let me know if there is any other standard way to do this

```
//Sample code
public void someMethod(){
depA.foo();
depB.bar();
}
//Sample Test
@Test(expectedExceptions = {RuntimeException.class})
public void someTest(){
when(depA.foo()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Some method"));
try{
 toTestClass.someMethod();
} finally {
 verify(depB,times(0)).bar();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, I use something like that:

```
@Test
public void someTest(){
    when(depA.foo()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Some method"));
    boolean hasException = false;
    try{
        toTestClass.someMethod();
    } catch(RuntimeException e) {
        hasException = true;
    }
    assertTrue(hasException);
    verify(depB,times(0)).bar();
}
```

Why?

1. I think `expectedExceptions` should only be used when you just want
   to check exceptions. Not a mix of assertions.
2. You don't want to `verify` if the exception
   didn't append.

*Edit:*
You can use a 3rd party assertion lib like AssertJ too. AssertJ deals well with exceptions.
See its documentation: https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#exception-assertion

```
@Test
public void someTest(){
     when(depA.foo()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Some method"));
     assertThatThrownBy(() -> { toTestClass.someMethod() })
                        .isInstanceOf(RuntimeException.class)
                        .hasMessageContaining("Some method");
     verify(depB,times(0)).bar();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. so catching is the only way it seems.. Was hoping if there was a more standard construct to avoid boiler plate code in every such test case

Comment: I updated my answer. You can remove boiler plate code with 3rd party lib like AssertJ.

Comment: Thanks for the reference

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ignoreException` of the [Fisbowl](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/fishbowl/) library.

```
@Test
public void someTest(){
   when(depA.foo()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Some method"));
   ignoreException(() -> toTestClass.someMethod());
   verify(depB,times(0)).bar();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the details